# Implementing custom number code into tkinter script

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So I've been working on a bit of code that is almost done. It is a simple GUI program that runs specific equations on the fly based on inputs. Thanks to a user on this site (wwii), I am able to use a custom number input format in the code he provided. The last thing I need to do, is implement his code to mine to have it all work together. With my code, there are 4 entry boxes, two of which refer to a specific location on a line (this is where the custom number format is input) and two which refer to measurements from those locations on the line to the same point. After all boxes have data, there are two results shown. One result is the length of a line at a right angle from the line. The second result is the exact location on the line to place it (this is where the custom number format outputs).

For example, If I put measurement locations on the line of 120 and 140, with measurements from those locations of 10 and 15, respectively, I get a result of 7.262 (length of a line at a right angle from the line) and a measurement of 126.875. With the code wwii helped me with, I would like to have the input boxes of 120 and 140 and the output box of 126.875 use the number format, which would look like this: 1+20.00, 1+40.00, and 1+26.88.

The code wwii helped me with does a direct convert of these number formats, but I would like to have those input fields read and convert it when it is typed in as 1+20, and for the calculation to show in the custom format as well.

I know that was long winded, however, I hope it makes sense. Here is a copy of my code (not very long) and the code that wwii helped me with. It did not like me separating into separate code boxes so the code wwii helped me with is added at the bottom of the code block.

```
from tkinter import *
from math import *

def show_entry_fields():
     try:
          a, c, d, e, = float(e1.get()), float(e3.get()), float(e4.get()), float(e5.get())
          b = e - d
          s = (a + b + c) / 2
          height = (sqrt (s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c)) * 2) / b
          height = float(format(height, '.3f'))
          height_label['text'] = str(height)
          side =((sqrt ((a ** 2) - (height ** 2))) + d)
          side = float(format(side, '.3f'))
          side_label['text'] = str(side)
     except ValueError:
          pass
     master.after(100, show_entry_fields)

master = Tk()
master.attributes("-topmost", True)
master.title("Triangulation Plotting")

Label(master, text="Measurement #1 Station Line Location").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
e4 = Entry(master)
e4.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=E)

Label(master, text="Triangulation Measurement #1").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
e1 = Entry(master)
e1.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=E)

Label(master, text="Measurement #2 Station Line Location").grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
e5 = Entry(master)
e5.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=E)

Label(master, text="Triangulation Measurement #2").grid(row=7, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
e3 = Entry(master)
e3.grid(row=7, column=1, sticky=E, pady=4)

Label(master, text="Offset from station line").grid(row=8, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
height_label = Label(master, text="")
height_label.grid(row=8, column=1)

Label(master, text="Measurement on Station Line").grid(row=9, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
side_label = Label(master, text="")
side_label.grid(row=9, column=1)

master.after(100,show_entry_fields)
master.mainloop()

Custom number format code from wwii:
def convert(thing):
    if isinstance(thing, str):
        a,b = thing.split('+')
        b,*d = b.split('.')
        d = '00' if not d else d[0]
        thing = round(float(f'{a}{b}.{d}'), 2)
    elif isinstance(thing, (int,float)):
        thing = str(round(thing, 2))
        thing,*d = thing.split('.')
        d = '00' if not d else d[0]
        thing = thing if len(thing) > 2 else '0'+thing
        thing = f'{thing[:-2]}+{thing[-2:]}.{d}'
    return thing
```

Thanks ahead of time for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the code that was provided for you by wwii can convert between formats. Thus there is not much that you have to do with your code to make it work. First off, move the code form wwii to the beginning of your program. Then, you only have to change 2 lines in function `show_entry_fields`.

First one is: `a, c, d, e = float(e1.get()), float(e3.get()), float(e4.get()), float(e5.get())`
You have to change it to: `a, c, d, e = float(e1.get()), float(e3.get()), convert(str(e4.get())), convert(str(e5.get()))`

Second one is: `side = float(format(side, '.3f'))`
You have to change it to: `side = convert(float(format(side, '.3f')))`

After doing this you can type 1+20 and 1+40 into entries near *Measurement #1 station line location* and *Measurement #2 station line location* and you'll get the converted result at *Measurement on station line*.

The main idea of all this is to do the conversions after the input and before any calculations (hence the changes in the first line) and do the conversion after all calculations but before the display of the output (hence the changes in the second line).

Here is the whole piece of code:

```
from tkinter import *
from math import *


# Custom number format code from wwii:
def convert(thing):
    if isinstance(thing, str):
        a,b = thing.split('+')
        b,*d = b.split('.')
        d = '00' if not d else d[0]
        thing = round(float(f'{a}{b}.{d}'), 2)
    elif isinstance(thing, (int,float)):
        thing = str(round(thing, 2))
        thing,*d = thing.split('.')
        d = '00' if not d else d[0]
        thing = thing if len(thing) > 2 else '0'+thing
        thing = f'{thing[:-2]}+{thing[-2:]}.{d}'
    return thing


def show_entry_fields():
    try:
        a, c, d, e = float(e1.get()), float(e3.get()), convert(str(e4.get())), convert(str(e5.get()))
        b = e - d
        s = (a + b + c) / 2
        height = (sqrt (s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c)) * 2) / b
        height = float(format(height, '.3f'))
        height_label['text'] = str(height)
        side =((sqrt ((a ** 2) - (height ** 2))) + b)
        side = convert(float(format(side, '.3f')))
        side_label['text'] = str(side)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    master.after(100, show_entry_fields)


master = Tk()
master.attributes("-topmost", True)
master.title("Triangulation Plotting")

Label(master, text="Measurement #1 Station Line Location").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
e4 = Entry(master)
e4.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=E)

Label(master, text="Triangulation Measurement #1").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
e1 = Entry(master)
e1.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=E)

Label(master, text="Measurement #2 Station Line Location").grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
e5 = Entry(master)
e5.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=E)

Label(master, text="Triangulation Measurement #2").grid(row=7, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
e3 = Entry(master)
e3.grid(row=7, column=1, sticky=E, pady=4)

Label(master, text="Offset from station line").grid(row=8, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
height_label = Label(master, text="")
height_label.grid(row=8, column=1)

Label(master, text="Measurement on Station Line").grid(row=9, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
side_label = Label(master, text="")
side_label.grid(row=9, column=1)

master.after(100, show_entry_fields)
master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I kept placing "convert" in the wrong position in the output and did not put it anywhere on the input. I figured it'd be something simple and you proved it. Once again, thank you very much for your help.